# How to use appcmd in Powershell Invoke-Command to add a virtual directory?

Tags: powershell, virtual-directory, invoke-command, appcmd

I want to use appcmd with Invoke-Command in Powershell to add a virtual directory.

I am using reference from:
1) [appcmd to create virtual directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory)
2) [Powershell Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6#examples)

Here is the code snippet:

```
$appCmdCommand2 = [string]::Format(
{"appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /+"[name='Default Web Site'].[path='/'].[path='/MyWebsite/dev',physicalPath='{0}']" /commit:apphost"},$folderName)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName ComputerAA -ScriptBlock {$appCmdCommand2}
```

When I run the code above, I keep getting error saying:

```
Unexpected token 'name='Default Web Site'].[path='/'].[path='/MyWebsite/dev'' in expression or statement.
```

I am new to Powershell and I have been searching everywhere how to solve this problem.

If anyone could show me how to correct my Powershell snippet so I could create a virtual directory? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may have a quoting issue combined with some extraneous characters. The `{}` characters in the String.Format call aren't doing anything for you. The double quote here `"appcmd.exe` starts a string that ends at `/+"` which makes everything after it error. You can escape the double quote in the string with a backtick ` character.

```
[string]::Format("appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /+`"[name='Default Web Site'].[path='/'].[path='/MyWebsite/dev',physicalPath='{0}']`" /commit:apphost",$folderName)
```

Powershell also has the -f operator which does string formatting without having to call string.format but you still need to escape the quotes.

```
$appCmdCommand2 = "appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /+`"[name='Default Web Site'].[path='/'].[path='/MyWebsite/dev',physicalPath='{0}']`" /commit:apphost" -f $folderName

Invoke-Command -ComputerName ComputerAA -ScriptBlock {$appCmdCommand2}
```